# Install4J 8 not creating JRE bundles

Tags: install4j

I am trying to create an installer with Install4J 8, bundling OpenJDK8. However, when building the installer, it downloads the JRE but then cannot find the downloaded JRE.

```
  Creating JRE bundle:
    Finding JDK release openjdk8/jdk8u212-b04 [windows-amd64]
    Downloading OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_8u212b04.zip (100%)
    Processing downloaded JDK archive

Build failed.

Cause: java.io.FileNotFoundException
       /home/jens/.install4j8/jres/original/c9aab7b767498c7a88df1b985f6897f2219f4794/OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_8u212b04.zip (Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden)
Stack trace:

com.exe4j.a.d: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/jens/.install4j8/jres/original/c9aab7b767498c7a88df1b985f6897f2219f4794/OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_8u212b04.zip (Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden)
    at com.install4j.b.r.b(ejt:230)
    at com.install4j.gui.b.run(ejt:100)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/jens/.install4j8/jres/original/c9aab7b767498c7a88df1b985f6897f2219f4794/OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_8u212b04.zip (Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
    at com.ejt.framework.d.y.a(ejt:14)
    at com.install4j.jdk.q$b.a(ejt:29)
    at com.install4j.jdk.q.a(ejt:37)
    at com.install4j.jdk.h.a(ejt:166)
    at com.install4j.jdk.h.a(ejt:139)
    at com.install4j.jdk.h.a(ejt:17)
    at com.install4j.jdk.j.a(ejt:126)
    at com.install4j.jdk.j.invoke(ejt:17)
    at com.install4j.jdk.aa$a.a(ejt:18)
    at com.install4j.jdk.ak.a(ejt:61)
    at com.install4j.jdk.h.b(ejt:103)
    at com.install4j.jdk.h.a(ejt:60)
    at com.install4j.b.l.a(ejt:34)
    at com.install4j.b.f.g(ejt:942)
    at com.install4j.b.f.a(ejt:909)
    at com.install4j.b.f.V(ejt:890)
    at com.install4j.b.r.a(ejt:491)
    at com.install4j.b.r.b(ejt:163)
    ... 1 more
```

Indeed there is no file in /home/jens/.install4j8/jres/original/c9aab7b767498c7a88df1b985f6897f2219f4794/

I have defined the JRE to be used in the General Settings and do not override those on the individual media.

Any ideas?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with the same JDK, please send a test project to support@ej-technologies.com where this is reproducible.

Comment: Thanks Ingo, I sent a test project to the address you suggested. Let me know if I can provide anything else or can assist analysis / debugging with additional validations. Thanks!